# Linux kernel memory management?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Will Linux Kernel free kmalloc'ed and not kfree'd in kernel module memory after module release just like it's work with user space apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The kernel will not do any garbage collection for a module.  If the module `kmalloc`s a chunk of memory and doesn't `kfree` it before the module is unloaded, that chunk will stay allocated and inaccessible until the next reboot.

Comment: The kernel will not do any garbage collection, and also will not free memory when the module exits. The latter is the key difference to a userspace process, which has all it's memory returned to the system when it exits.

Comment: Note that exactly the same thing applies in userspace, if you write a module that is loaded using `dlopen()`.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the kernel will not do any garbage collection for a module but device drivers can use `devm_*` types of resource allocations (called managed resource allocation functions) and the kernel will do all the required cleanups after there is no more reference to the device.

See here for the commented source code in the kernel source for [devm_kmalloc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/devres.c#L788).